# Crash with Room Migration to a new version

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have database with table Profile with version 1. Now I want to alter that table and add text field createdAt.

I have created Migration:

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
@Override public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Profile "+ " ADD COLUMN createdAt TEXT");
}
};
```

I have add it here:

```
 @Provides @Singleton public AppDatabase  provideDatabase(@Named(DIConstants.APP) Context context) {
 return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "appdb")
    .addMigrations(AppDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2)
    .build();
  }
```

Now when I run the app I get this error:

```
Process: org.app.app.debug, PID: 4800
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/org.app.rapp.debug/databases/appdb
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1659)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                  at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:240)
                  at org.app.app.data.sql.AppDatabase$1.migrate(AppDatabase.java:65)
                  at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:73)
                  at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                  at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
                  at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
                  at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:305)
                  at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:281)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: i went through the same process while altering my tables in room. The logs won't help you at all , since they don't point towards the exact issue. You must write test case to know whats exactly going wrong here. You can follow android documentation for that https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to write test, here is my question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155165/android-room-can-not-create-json-schema-for-testing-migrations Have you experienced this problem?

Comment: No i haven't experienced that one. What you can do is just make sure in your modules, inside asset schema file is created.

Comment: I can not find schema file. I do not know why it does not generate it.

Comment: if schema file is not getting generated, you can't test the migration itself. What you can try is, remove your migration code but keep the room.schemaLocation annotation processor property in your build.gradle & build the project & check if schema is getting generated for 1st version of the database & after that go for version 2.

Comment: have you updated version to 2 ?

Answer (score -2):

Try making 'createdAt' nullable. This worked for me.

```
@Entity(tableName = "RSyncStatus")
data class RSyncStatus(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
                       var id: Long? = null,
                       var userObjId: String = "",
                       var syncStatus: Int? = null,
                       var test: String? = null)
```

I'm using **kotlin**. So I did mine from `var test`: `String = ""` to `var test`: `String? = null`
and it finally worked!

I think in java it goes like this:

```
private String test = null
```