# Android Room can not create JSON schema for testing migrations

Tags: android, android-room

I have created migration from 1 to 2 version of my database.

I have the app in a few modules like:

- app
- data
- domain

I have tried adding this into build.gradle of app and data modules:

```
javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":  "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
```

Here is my MigrationTest class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MigrationTest {

private static final String TEST_DB = "migration-test";

@Rule public MigrationTestHelper helper;

private Profile profile;

public MigrationTest() {
helper = new MigrationTestHelper(
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
    AppDatabase.class.getCanonicalName(),
    new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());
}

@Before
public void setUp(){
profile = createProfile();
}

@Test public void migrate1To2() throws IOException {
    SupportSQLiteDatabase db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 1);
    insertProfile(db);
    db.close();
    AppDatabase database = (AppDatabase) helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true, MIGRATION_1_2);
    Single<ProfileData> profileDataSingle = database.profileDao().getById("userId");
    ProfileData profileData = profileDataSingle.blockingGet();
    Profile currentProfile = ProfileMapper.transform(profileData);
    assertEquals(currentProfile.getUserId(), profile.getUserId());
}
```

Here is failing test:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find the schema file in the
>   assets folder. Make sure to include the exported json schemas in your
>   test assert inputs. See
>   https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration-testing
>   for details. Missing file: org.app.app.data.sql.AppDatabase/1.json

Comment: Can you please share part of your `AppDatabase` class? This happened to me. I solved it by making sure that the `version` in `AppDatabase` is set to `2` and the `schemas/*/1.json` and `schemas/*/2.json` files were generated before running the tests.

Comment: That is correct. I managed to solve it by generating 1.json and 2.json. I was trying to migrate to version 2, but did not have 1.json generated, since I had marked as export=false.

Comment: @Zookey How did you manage to migrate/upgrade from the previous version if it was marked as `export=false`? I'm trying to upgrade an app with the previous install version was set that way and I've only managed to crash all my tests. Is there a way to migrate from 1 to 2 where version 1 isn't exported and version 2 adds a column?

Comment: Im having same problem? do we have to generated schema  files ourself?

Comment: As far as I can remmeber, yes.

Answer (score 7):

For Kotliners:

```
android{
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        getByName("androidTest"){
            assets.srcDirs(File(projectDir, "schemas"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `srcDIrs()` adds paths relative to the project dir, I got it to work correctly using
`assets.srcDirs(File("schemas"))`

Comment: kapt doesn't work for build flavours, use javaCompileOptions instead

Answer (score 5):

For me it helps, when I add this (I simply forgot it). Maybe it helps someone

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution in Kotlin is:
Add the following to `build.gradle(app)`:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
   kapt {
        arguments {
            arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    getByName("androidTest") {
        assets.srcDirs(files(projectDir, "schemas"))
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3'
   kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3'
   annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3'
   implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.3'
}
```

P.S: Dont Forget to set `exportSchema = true` in the `Database file`.

Comment: what database file?

Comment: I mean AppDatabase file. For more info, have a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to Zookey. All I was doing wrong was looking for a schema file that didn't exist. I was testing migration 8 to 9, but version 8.json wasn't generated. I had to created my database from version 9.json instead, and test from there.

Answer (score 0):

Happens because the json schema for the migration version is not found in schemas folder.

For instance, if you are testing migration from version 1 to 2, the file /schemas/*/1.json **must exist**.